# Weird Google Scholar results

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

Today I tried to get the amount of papers (roughly) since 2004. 
But while playing around in Google Scholar I noticed that I get more results when I filter with the "since 2016" button than with the "since 2015" button.

In my understanding, the "since 2015" filter should include everything that was published after 2015, so 2016 as well.

And Google didn't mess up, because the "since 2015" results contain elements that were published in 2016.

[2015 search](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?as_ylo=2015&q=probabilistic+database&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5)

[image: 2015 result]

[2016 search](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=probabilistic+database&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5)

[image: 2016 result]

## Edit

Another fun fact: When you enter a custom timeframe and search for articles from 2015-2016, you get 100 results more than searching from 2015-*blank*.

Comment: One issue could be that the numbers of results reported in a Google search are an approximation. (Hence the "about", meaning "approximately".)

Comment: @AlE. yeah, but shouldn't the results that were published since 2015 include the results from 2016? I would understand, if 2015 and 2016 had roughly the same amount of publications in this topic each, but this suggests that in the last two years, there were less publications than last year...

Comment: Makes sense to me, but Google's algorithms probably don't take that into account.

Comment: @AlE. the output would make sense if the results from the 2015 search wouldn't contain results that were published in 2016. so google does some weird filtering of the results depending on the wanted timeframe.

Comment: A lot of stuff Google does is inscrutable.

Comment: [This article at Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559) talks about this same issue in  Google's general search.

Comment: What is the question?